# How to fetch numbers from ping result?

Tags: unix, grep, solaris, ping

I did a ping experiment `ping -s www.google.com 56 5` on sunOS, and the result is:

```
PING www.google.com: 56 data bytes
64 bytes from iad23s26-in-f18.1e100.net (173.194.121.50): icmp_seq=0. time=8.72 ms
64 bytes from iad23s26-in-f18.1e100.net (173.194.121.50): icmp_seq=1. time=8.69 ms
64 bytes from iad23s26-in-f18.1e100.net (173.194.121.50): icmp_seq=2. time=8.61 ms
64 bytes from iad23s26-in-f18.1e100.net (173.194.121.50): icmp_seq=3. time=8.54 ms
64 bytes from iad23s26-in-f18.1e100.net (173.194.121.50): icmp_seq=4. time=8.62 ms

----www.google.com PING Statistics----
5 packets transmitted, 5 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip (ms)  min/avg/max/stddev = 8.54/8.64/8.72/0.073
```

What I need are the numbers of packets received`5`, packet loss`0`, min`8.45`, avg`8.64` and max`8.72`.

I was trying to use `>` to store the result in a file. What I want is `5, 0, 8.45, 8.64, 8.72`.

Can I use `grep` to do this? Do you have a better way?

Comment: Not Linux, in fact ping syntax in Linux is different. Please fix your tags.

Comment: Which version of SunOS do you use and do have GNU grep installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take you most of the way.

```
ping -s www.google.com 56 5 | awk '/transmitted/ {print $1,$4,$7}; /round-trip/ {print $5}' | sed -e 's/[\/\% ]/,/g'
```

This will net you:

```
5,5,0,
8.54,8.64,8.72,0.073
```

From here you simply need to assign it into a variable in bash and manipulate it as you see fit:

```
RESULT=`ping -s www.google.com 56 5 | awk '/transmitted/ {print $1,$4,$7}; /round-trip/ {print $5}' | sed -e 's/[\/\% ]/,/g'`
```